# Trying to launch in the mouse position in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the player character to launch in the direction of the mouse based on a launch range.

The problem is that I do not know how I would go about doing this. I attempted it anyway and here is the code I came up with.

```
public class playershoot : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float shootRange = 5f;

   Vector2 shootDir;
   Vector2 lookDir;
   public Rigidbody2D rb;
   public Camera cam;

   Vector2 mousePos;
   void FixedUpdate()
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("huzza!");
       mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

       if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("huzza!");
           lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
           rb.MovePosition(rb.position + lookDir * shootRange);
    }
}
```

I know it looks really bad and I was going to clean it up a lot once I got it working. Unfortunately, I never got to that point. Any tips?

Comment: Do you want to just fire an object in the direction it is facing? `rb.AddForce(transform.forward * yourFace);`. Do you want the launch position to originate from the mouse click on the screen?

Comment: Please, not that you syntax regarding the if statement looks weird. In c#, if you want to execute many statements inside an if statement, you need to enclose a scope with curly brackets { }. Otherwise, only the first statement after the if will be considered by the if.

Comment: I fixed your indentation to emphasize @RodrigoRodrigues 's comment

Comment: @derHugo, I will revert your edit, but write an answer with both the before and after adding the braces, so it won't lose context.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have much context about your problem, but there is one thing that catches attention in you `if` statement.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("huzza!");
    mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("huzza!");
       lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
       rb.MovePosition(rb.position + lookDir * shootRange);
}
```

In c#, if you want to execute many statements inside an if statement, you need to enclose a scope with curly brackets { }. Otherwise, only the first statement after the if will be considered by the if.

With this code as is, only the line `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("huzza!");` will be conditionally executed when `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is true. The following two lines are executed outside the if. That means, no matter if input is captured or not, `rb.MovePosition` will happen on every frame by update.

You probably meant this:

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("huzza!");
       lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
       rb.MovePosition(rb.position + lookDir * shootRange);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this still does not work. I've edited the question and posted a new one since i know if i just edited this i never would have gotten a reply. could you please take a look at it?